# Evaluating the improper integral $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-(2x+7y)}\mathop{\mathrm dy} \mathop{\mathrm dx} $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

> Evaluate the given improper integral
>
> $$\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-(2x+7y)}\mathop{\mathrm dy} \mathop{\mathrm dx} $$

Here is what I tried:

$$\int_0^\infty\lim\limits_{t \to \infty}[e^{-2x-7y}]_0^t \mathop{\mathrm dx}=\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \int_0^t \frac{1}{7}e^{-2x}\mathop{\mathrm dx}= -\frac{1}{7}$$

Comment: @Isko10986 $1/14$, I reckon. The integrand is always positive.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri o yeah, I forgot to multiply the other negative. My bad. Should be $\frac{1}{14}$. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** this problem actually reduces to calculating

$$\left(\int_0^{\infty}e^{-2x}\,dx\right)\cdot\left(\int_0^{\infty}e^{-7y}\,dy\right)$$

Why?

Comment: Thank you I got it. Is it because you can split up the x and y into two separate integrals? Here is the solution, I didn't want to manually edit because it takes long to type integrals and limits: http://imgur.com/a/dgz5d

Comment: That's right! Notice this happens because the exponential has the property that $$e^{a+b}=e^a \cdot e^b$$, so the variables can be separated.